# Angular 5 not updating the dom after receiving async message from Electron IPC, this suppose to be simple but it's not very obvious

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, observable

I have a service and a component that I want to update the array of string only if I receive response from electron IPC.

#### This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GeneralService } from '../../service/general.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sub-cmp',
  templateUrl: './sub-cmp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sub-cmp.component.css']
})
export class SubCmpComponent implements OnInit {

  textOutput: String;
  arrStr: string[];
  constructor(private srv: GeneralService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.textOutput = '';
    this.arrStr = [];
    // Listen for async-reply message from main process
    this.srv.on('async-reply', (event, arg) => {
      console.log(arg);
      this.arrStr.push(arg);
    });
  }

  asyncButton(): void {
    this.srv.sendAsync(this.textOutput.toString());
  }
}
```

### The Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

const CHANNEL = {
  'sendAsync': 'async',
  'sendSync': 'synchronous-message',
  'getAsync': 'async-reply'
};
@Injectable()
export class GeneralService {
  constructor(protected electron: ElectronService) {
  }

  /**
   * Send Async message
   * @param msgVal Message to send
   */
  public sendAsync(msgVal: string): void {
    if (this.electron.isElectronApp) {
      this.electron.ipcRenderer.send(CHANNEL.sendAsync, msgVal);
    } else {
      console.log('isElectronApp==false');
    }
  }

  /**
   * Recieve async message
   */
  on(channel: string, callback) {
    if (this.electron.isElectronApp) {
      return this.electron.ipcRenderer.on(channel, callback);
    } else {
      console.log('isElectronApp==false');
    }
  }

}
```

I do receive the current data but the DOM doesn't update.
Is there any simple way to do it ???

The issue I have is at `this.arrStr.push(arg);` which suppose to add the new data to the array and update the DOM but it updates the DOM only when I change the input field (HTML).

Comment: Have you tried to use an Observable and to subscribe to it?  Observables are designed to take care of the synchronization on any internal state change to the linked data.

Comment: Yes I have tried to use Observable but still unable to figure out